# For loop? For why and for how

Tags: python

Quick question! For loops are still confusing to me as to why a certain part works. An example is:

```
user_text = input()
count = o

for char in user_text:
   if not (char in ".,"):
       count += 1
print(count)
```

The parts in question are:

1. where the char comes from in the for char section. is this a variable that I am creating or is this a Python built-in tool?
2. why do we have count +=1? Is this needed for the loop to work? If so why?

Comment: How i'd explain it: The input will return a string, a for loop iterating over a string will iterate over each character of a string so char is a sort of temporary variable just for that loop, containing a the first character on the first iteration, the second character on the second iteration etc.... As for count, it isn't required to have the for loop work, it's just a counter that has been added by whoever designed the text to count how many of the characters aren't a full stop or comma(by adding 1 every time char is not in ".," and then printing at the end)

Comment: "where the char comes from in the for char section." It comes from `user_text`. That's how the loop works. If you mean "how did we know to write `char` here, instead of writing something else?", then it **does not actually matter** - this is just a variable name, which you get to choose. The name `char` is **not special in any way**, and does not change how the loop works. "Why do we have to count +=1 to have to for loop to work?" **We don't**. That's just the code **that is being repeated** by the loop.

Comment: Please read [ask] and note that this is **not a discussion forum**. If you need fundamental concepts explained, [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [look them up with a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+for+loop+tutorial) first, and then try an actual discussion forum such as Reddit or Quora. Because we don't have discussions here, we can't properly explain concepts - because we **don't know what you don't understand about them, or why**.

Comment: i'd say it's rather obvious what he doesn't understand by his question, and this is a q&a website, he asked a question, it's not like he'll find it anywhere on the internet if every response to a question like this is like yours

Comment: @Pwuurple just because this "is a q&a website" doesn't mean that every possible question is on topic, or that they fit the format. There are requirements for questions here. I already explicitly gave OP suggestions for specific places where the question would fit, because their guidelines will be different from the ones here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When creating a loop, you must put a loop control variable. In this case it is char. You declare it when you are making your for loop. You can change that to whatever you want. I usually put "I".

The count +=1 isn't necessary for a loop to work, this is only adding 1 every time your if statement is true. At the end it will print your count, letting you know how many times your if statement saw true

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know that we are assigning a variable in the actual for loop itself that explains so much now. Since this is the case the count incrementing would make sense depending on the instance. You are a life saver, hats off to you.

Answer (score -2):

1. where the char comes from in the for char section.

   you need to type a text until you press enter key
2. why do we have to count +=1 to have to for loop to work?

   you don't need you can change it to pass, i.e.:

   ```
   if not (char in ".,"):
        pass
   ```

**EDIT:** Also, you need to change variable `count = 0`